# Why does Eclipse sometimes hang when my program connects to JBoss

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Sometimes when I run my project, that connects to JBoss, it will hang.

For example here is the log output for when it hangs:

```
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.5.Final
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:58 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@29f5ca0b, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <71c88986>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=DevApp00:DevApp00]} on channel Channel ID ec955d48 (outbound) of Remoting connection 04a8743d to devapp00.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:59 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:59 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@29f5ca0b, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6d5bcb39>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=DevApp01:DevApp01]} on channel Channel ID c9163bbe (outbound) of Remoting connection 50ba181a to devapp01.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:59 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Dec 14, 2021 11:57:59 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@29f5ca0b, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <7900f3c9>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=DevApp01:DevApp01]} on channel Channel ID aa5e4733 (outbound) of Remoting connection 6075ef24 to /XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX
```

Here is the log output when it doesn't hang:

```
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:42 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.5.Final
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:42 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:42 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:42 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@4ae0a5dc, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <71ed5401>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=DevApp00:DevApp00]} on channel Channel ID b0b91086 (outbound) of Remoting connection 11244593 to devapp00.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@4ae0a5dc, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <3f7dbbe3>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=DevApp01:DevApp01]} on channel Channel ID a49da456 (outbound) of Remoting connection 7900f3c9 to devapp01.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext registerEJBReceiver
INFO: Added a new EJB receiver in cluster context ejb for node DevApp01:DevApp01. Total nodes in cluster context = 1
Dec 14, 2021 11:58:43 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext registerEJBReceiver
INFO: Added a new EJB receiver in cluster context ejb for node DevApp00:DevApp00. Total nodes in cluster context = 2
```

Here is my jboss-ejb-client.properties

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

invocation.timeout=3000
reconnect.tasks.timeout=2000

remote.connections=dev1,dev2

remote.clusters=ejb

# Dev1 - Node 1
remote.connection.dev1.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.dev1.connect.options.org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL=300000
remote.connection.dev1.host=devapp00.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com
remote.connection.dev1.port=XXXX
remote.connection.dev1.username=XXXXXXXXXX
remote.connection.dev1.password=XXXXXXXXXX

# Dev2 - Node 2
remote.connection.dev2.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.dev2.connect.options.org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL=300000
remote.connection.dev2.host=devapp01.magcore.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com
remote.connection.dev2.port=XXXX
remote.connection.dev2.username=XXXXXXXXXX
remote.connection.dev2.password=XXXXXXXXXX

# cluster 1
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.timeout=2500
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.cluster.ejb.username=XXXXXXXXXX
#Dev Password
remote.cluster.ejb.password=XXXXXXXXXX
```

This morning I tried 26 times and is hung every time, but it doesn't always hang.
If I deploy this via WebStart, it seems to work just fine.

Interestingly, it seems as if it is hanging on setting up the cluster. I don't know why I didn't see this before, but it doesn't really help me solve the problem.

Comment: *How* do you run your project?

Comment: @nitind I have a "Run Configuration" set up.